# JDBC ResultSet to a DataTable in Google Visualization API?

Tags: java, jdbc, google-api, google-visualization

Is there a general method to convert a JDBC ResultSet to a Google Visualization [DataTable](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/google/visualization/visualization-datasource/1.0.1/visualization-datasource-1.0.1-javadoc.jar!/com/google/visualization/datasource/datatable/DataTable.html) object?

It seems like there would be such a thing that uses ResultSetMetaData to create [ColumnDescription](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/google/visualization/visualization-datasource/1.0.1/visualization-datasource-1.0.1-javadoc.jar!/com/google/visualization/datasource/datatable/ColumnDescription.html) objects and then iterate populates rows.  But darn if I can find it via Google search.

Since both [ResultSetMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) and DataTable have so many special properties, wanted to double check here before starting down the garden path of writing a custom method.

Answer (score 0):

The class [com.google.visualization.datasource.util.SqlDataSourceHelper](http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-java/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/com/google/visualization/datasource/util/SqlDataSourceHelper.java?r=46) has two static methods `buildColumns()` and `buildRows()` that take care of this:

```
  ...
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(queryString);

  DataTable table = buildColumns(rs, columnIdsList);
  buildRows(table, rs);
  return table;
```

These are called from the top method `executeQuery(...)` and in turn call other methods in the class, that handle the various translation steps.  It's said to work only with MySQL but the code is transparent enough to customize for other target database.

```
   sqlTypeToValueType(metaData.getColumnType(i));
```